# Group values in querystring generated with .serialize

Tags: jquery

I have a form:

```
<form id="formFilter">    
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" id="type_red" value="red" ?>
    <label for="type_red">Red</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="type" id="blue" value="Blue" ?>
<label for="type_blue">Blue</label>
</form>
```

Then, I am using this jQuery to serialize the fields:

```
fp("#formFilter").submit(function(){
    var querystring = fp(this).serialize();
    fp('#result').html(querystring);
    return false;
});
```

This returns the string `type=Red&type=Blue`

Except that I need a string like this: `type=Red,Blue`

I will appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name to make them group automagically, from:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type" id="type_red" value="red" ?>
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="type_red" value="red" ?>
```

This will group them on the serverside.

If for some strange reason all you're trying to do is create a string, you could do:

```
$("#formFilter").on('submit', function(){
    var qs = $(this).serializeArray(),
        q = {},
        querystring = "?";

    $.each(qs, function(idx, arr) {
        if (q[arr.name] === undefined) q[arr.name] = [];
        q[arr.name].push(arr.value);
    });

    $.each(q, function(name, value) {
        querystring += (name + "=" + value.join(',') + "&");
    });

    querystring = querystring.substring(0, querystring.length - 1);

    $('#result').html(querystring);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Adding the [] returns type+%5B%5D=Red&type+%5B%5D=Blue

Comment: Yes it does, but on the serverside, the values will be joined together. I'll change the answer a bit.